# Gulp is hanging. Just stop working without change to JS

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have been working on a project for the past few months using the same gulp file. However when I was compiling some CSS, the gulp task is just hanging and is not compiling the SASS. I do not know what is going on because the file wasn't even open when it stopped working Gulp file is below, any help would be great.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var batch = require('gulp-batch');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

function onError(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(sourcemaps);
}

var config = {
    bootstrapDir: './bower_components/bootstrap-sass',
    publicDir: './css',
};

var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


//Auto Prefixer

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('./css/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [config.bootstrapDir + '/assets/stylesheets'],
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.bootstrapDir + '/assets/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + '/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'fonts', 'sass', 'prefixer'], function() {
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('./sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(sass({includePaths: ['./bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets']}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
  //    .pipe(livereload({ start: true }));
});

gulp.task('prefixer', ['css', 'fonts', 'sass'], function () {
    return gulp.src('./css/app.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
     console.log('prefixer');
 });

gulp.watch('sass/_partials/**/*.scss', function () { 
    console.log('Gulping...');
    gulp.start('sass');
    gulp.start('prefixer');
    console.log('Done!');
   // livereload.listen();
 });

gulp.task('default', function() {
   return gutil.log('Gulp is running!')
});
```

The response at the moment is:

```
[15:18:58] Finished 'css' after 3.58 ms
[15:18:58] gulp-debug: sass/app.scss
[15:18:58] gulp-debug: 1 item
[15:18:58] Finished 'fonts' after 10 ms
[15:18:59] Finished 'sass' after 323 ms
[15:18:59] Starting 'prefixer'...
[15:18:59] Finished 'prefixer' after 298 ms
```

I think it is something to do with the watch function not working properly, but not to sure

Comment: does the source path mentioned inside task named 'sass' and watch is correct?

Comment: Just started seeing this too.

Comment: @joemaller I have had to remove the watch function and just compile manually

Comment: @SamKelham I'm seeing this even without watch, basically `return gulp.src(file).pipe(gulp.dest(dest))` is hanging. I updated node today, but also wiped and re-installed node_modules. :(

Comment: Well, I've got no idea. I just rebuilt my entire gulpfile one task at a time and it's all working. No changes. Maybe a watch call got orphaned or something.